# The httpResponseMsg return nothing form php file

Tags: php, android

When I try to run my code just I have empty value in the Tost form PHP file.
So how to solve this problem?

[image]

```
package com.algorithm.software.catcher;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.ResponseCache;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class login_screen extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText Email, Password;
    Button LogIn ;
    String PasswordHolder, EmailHolder;
    String finalResult ;
    String HttpURL = "https://localhost/user_login.php";
    Boolean CheckEditText ;


    HashMap<String,String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
    HttpParse httpParse = new HttpParse();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        Email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.p_e);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        LogIn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.log);

        LogIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot();

                if(CheckEditText){

                    UserLoginFunction(EmailHolder, PasswordHolder);

                }
                else {

                    Toast.makeText(login_screen.this, "Please fill all form fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });
    }
    public void CheckEditTextIsEmptyOrNot(){

        EmailHolder = Email.getText().toString();
        PasswordHolder = Password.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(EmailHolder) || TextUtils.isEmpty(PasswordHolder))
        {
            CheckEditText = false;
        }
        else {

            CheckEditText = true ;
        }
    }

    public void UserLoginFunction(final String email, final String password){

        class UserLoginClass extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String httpResponseMsg) {

                super.onPostExecute(httpResponseMsg);



                if(httpResponseMsg.equalsIgnoreCase("Data Matched")){

                    finish();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(login_screen.this, WELCOME.class);
                    startActivity(intent);


                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(login_screen.this,httpResponseMsg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                }

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                hashMap.put("email",params[0]);

                hashMap.put("password",params[1]);

                finalResult = httpParse.postRequest(hashMap, HttpURL);

                return finalResult;
            }
        }

        UserLoginClass userLoginClass = new UserLoginClass();

        userLoginClass.execute(email,password);
    }

}
```

And this is my php file:

```
<?php

include 'catcher_connction.php';
$con = mysqli_connect($HostName, $HostUser, $HostPass, $DatabaseName);

$u_email    = $_POST['email'];
$u_password = $_POST['password'];

$Sql_Query = "SELECT * FROM trader WHERE Email = '$u_email' and Password = '$u_password' ";

$check = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, $Sql_Query));

if (isset($check)) {
    echo "Data Matched";
} else {
    echo "Invalid Username or Password Please Try Again";
}
?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injections. Please consider using [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

Comment: You did not explain what your code should do. Then how should we know?

Comment: it is login code from mysql data base